# Python file write() not writing/formatting correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of times each number appears in a file, then print the original number and its count to another file. The original numbers are sorted in ascending order. The counts are close enough, but the problem is the end formatting. It is somehow reversing the order I print them!

This is my code:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    prevLine=f.readline()
    out = open(outfile,'w')
    for line in f:
        if line == prevLine:
            curCount = curCount+1
        else:
            out.write("%s \t\t %d\n" % (prevLine , curCount))
            curCount =1
        prevLine=line
    out.close()
```

The first few lines SHOULD look like this:

```
1     7935
2     4455
3     2956
```

There are 7,935 ones, 4,455 twos, and 2,956 threes.
But when I go look at the new file I created (outfile), I get this:

```
1
     7935
2
     4455
```

The newline should be at the end, not in between the numbers. Why is this happening?

Comment: It looks to me like a `collections.Counter` would be useful here ...

Comment: @mgilson Oh, thanks for the suggestion! I just researched that and it looks a lot easier. Unfortunately, I have Python 2.6.5, and Counter is not available. I don't think I can update it, either, since I am using the Python version that comes with ArcGIS.

Comment: There are usually backports on ActiveState for the various subclasses in collections.  See [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still have a linefeed at the end of `prevLine`, change your write line to the following:

```
out.write("%s \t\t %d\n" % (prevLine.rstrip() , curCount))
```

Comment: You might want to use `rstrip('\n')` if you want to remove newlines, but preserve other whitespace at the end. (For most text formats, you don't really care about trailing whitespace, but if you do, it's worth knowing how to deal with it.)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the newline character `\n` in `out.write("%s \t\t %d\n" % (prevLine , curCount))`

Also, it is not recommended to use the old printf formatting in python. Personally I prefer this one: `str_output="""{prev_line}\t\t {current_count}\n""".format(prev_line=prevLine,current_count=curCount)`

And like @mtadd 's answers says, use `rstrip()` to remove the newline from `prevLine` string.

giving:

```
str_output="{prev}\t\t {cur_cnt}\n".format(prev=prevLine.rstrip(),cur_cnt=curCount) 
out.write(str_output)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Though now with the newline, I am getting the prevLine number on it's own line, then on the next line are the tabs and the count. There is still a problem somewhere! I'll update my original post to show exactly what I mean.

Comment: I don't think its recommended to use the **printf formating** of string, this is old python. Rather try this `str_output="{prev_line}\t\t {current_count}\n".format(prev_line=prevLine,current_count=curCount)`. I have update my answer.

Comment: Oh, that is good to know! That did not seem to help the formatting at all, though.